# Error when executing PIG script

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm running a pig script in google cloud Hadoop environment 
    pig -useHCatalog -x mapreduce -f profile.pig
i have two tables each with 50,000 records that will be crossed and joined with a table with 10,00,000., I ran the same script with less record it run quite well but when i increase the record count it throws this error.

```
    2015-10-22 05:38:56,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:56,266 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=FAILED. Redirecting to job history serv
er
2015-10-22 05:38:56,377 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exceptio
n from backed error: Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137
Killed by external signal
2015-10-22 05:38:56,377 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2015-10-22 05:38:56,380 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 
HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
2.6.0.2.2.8.0-3150      0.14.0.2.2.8.0-3150     hdfs    2015-10-22 05:34:17     2015-10-22 05:38:56     HASH_JOIN,GROUP_BY,FILTER,CROSS,UNION
Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime      MinMapTime      AvgMapTime      MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime        Alias   Feature Outp
uts
job_1444401341866_0534  1       0       11      11      11      11      0       0       0       0       t_female,t_male,t_profile       MULTI_QUERY,MAP_ONLY
job_1444401341866_0535  2       1       6       6       6       6       91      91      91      91      t_female,t_male,t_raid_female,t_raid_female1
job_1444401341866_0536  2       1       25      25      25      25      89      89      89      89      t_female,t_male,t_raid_male,t_raid_male1
job_1444401341866_0537  2       0       5       5       5       5       0       0       0       0       t_female,t_male,t_mf_union      MAP_ONLY
Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1444401341866_0538  j_ci1,j_mf_education,j_mf_height,j_mf_occupation,j_mf_religion,j_mf_weight,t_ci1,t_mf_transpose,t_mf_union,t_raid       HASH_JOIN       Message: Job failed!
Input(s):
Successfully read 10001 records (1509451 bytes) from: "matrimony.profile_gce_limit"Input(s):
Successfully read 10001 records (1509451 bytes) from: "matrimony.profile_gce_limit"

Output(s):

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1444401341866_0534  ->      job_1444401341866_0535,job_1444401341866_0536,job_1444401341866_0537,
job_1444401341866_0535  ->      job_1444401341866_0538,
job_1444401341866_0536  ->      job_1444401341866_0538,
job_1444401341866_0537  ->      job_1444401341866_0538,
job_1444401341866_0538  ->      null,
null    ->      null,
null    ->      null,
null


2015-10-22 05:38:56,455 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:56,456 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:56,459 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-10-22 05:38:56,572 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:56,572 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:56,576 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-10-22 05:38:56,675 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:56,676 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:56,679 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-10-22 05:38:56,780 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:56,780 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:56,783 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-10-22 05:38:56,883 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:56,883 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:56,886 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-10-22 05:38:56,981 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/Backend error message
timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:56,982 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:56,985 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history s
erver
2015-10-22 05:38:57,083 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/
timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:57,083 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:57,086 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history s
erver
2015-10-22 05:38:57,182 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/
timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:57,182 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:57,185 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history s
erver
2015-10-22 05:38:57,275 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/
timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:57,275 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:57,278 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history s
erver
2015-10-22 05:38:57,370 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/
timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:57,370 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:57,373 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history s
erver
2015-10-22 05:38:57,475 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/
timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:57,475 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:57,478 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history s
erver
2015-10-22 05:38:57,570 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.TimelineClientImpl - Timeline service address: http://hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal:8188/ws/v1/
timeline/
2015-10-22 05:38:57,570 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-w-0.c.horton-cluster-3.internal/10.240.0.3:8050
2015-10-22 05:38:57,574 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history s
erver
2015-10-22 05:38:57,601 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2015-10-22 05:38:57,602 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Container killed on request. Exit code is 
137
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137
Killed by external signal
Details at logfile: /home/hdfs/workfile/pig_1445492051329.log
2015-10-22 05:38:57,603 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
Details at logfile: /home/hdfs/workfile/pig_1445492051329.log
2015-10-22 05:38:57,603 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
Details at logfile: /home/hdfs/workfile/pig_1445492051329.log
2015-10-22 05:38:57,603 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
Details at logfile: /home/hdfs/workfile/pig_1445492051329.log
2015-10-22 05:38:57,623 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 4 minutes, 46 seconds and 401 milliseconds (286401 ms)


And this is what it is in the log file

    ================================================================================
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:179)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:495)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
================================================================================
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:179)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:495)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
================================================================================
```

Comment: It's possible this is a problem with the memory allocation for your job. Are you able to up the mapreduce java options to give it a little more memory? If you're able to see the job logs on MR you might get more specific messages about what is happening.

Comment: Hey @JasonS, i'm new to hadoop i came this far only with the help of stack overflow. can you be more specific on what to do.?

Comment: i ran as pig -useHCatalog -x local script.pig it gives.java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:248)
        java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)

Comment: Maharaj : I am just wondering why we are seeing  these many jobs : job_1444401341866_0534 job_1444401341866_0535  job_1444401341866_0536  job_1444401341866_0537 in Job Stats . Could you provide some more info ? And  the error which you posted above :No space left on device" will only occur when your local server space is almost full.

Comment: So the thing is i'm loading two tables table1 had 100000 records and table2 has 1000000 record in table one i did un-pivoting joining doing some basic hive stuffs and then joining with table2 and then aggregating them, when i'm doing this same routine with smaller dataset it works fine but with larger dataset it's not the case

Comment: BTW, i have 1 master node and 2 slave node when i run the script it takes only one worker node and doing the actions i don't know why it not using both node.

Comment: "No space left on device" means that ... you guessed it there is No space left on the device.... fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, it was `OrcStorage('\t')`.

I made it to `OrcStorage()` and it worked.